# How do I scrape IP addresses through the use of BeautifulSoup and output to CSV?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://myip.ms/browse/blacklist/Blacklist_IP_Blacklist_IP_Addresses_Live_Database_Real-time'

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

ipList = soup.find("td",{"class": "row_name"})

rows = ipList.findAll('td')
for tr in rows:
  cols = td.findAll('td')
  if len(cols) > 0:
     print (ip.cols.text.strip())
```

I am doing web scraping using BeautifulSoup and I have encountered some problems. May I know why am I unable to scrape IP addresses from the database table. How do I output the results to a CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using `find()` for ipList, which fetches only one ip, you can use `findall()` or `select` which will return ip array.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url ='https://myip.ms/browse/blacklist/Blacklist_IP_Blacklist_IP_Addresses_Live_Database_Real-time'
response = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
ipList = soup.select(".row_name")
with open('ip_output.csv', 'w') as f:
    for ips in ipList:
        f.write(ips.find('a').text + '\n')
```

Output in `csv`

```
195.154.251.86
37.140.192.194
80.94.174.55
175.103.39.28
90.173.129.250
51.15.146.121
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you! But may I know what does proxies = proxies does?

Comment: My bad, ignore that proxies parameter, I just used it to pass firewall

Comment: Thank you for helping me solved my problem! Greatly appreciated!